# Icons not showing up in tab bar IconPagerIndicator

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I'm following a tutorial to get icons in a tab bar made by the ViewPagerIndicator library, but they don't show up. The titles appear, and the getIconsResId method gets called, but nevertheless the icons can't be seen.

This is the code I use for my PageAdapter class. It is almost an exact copy of the sample file in the library.

```
public class IconsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements IconPagerAdapter {

protected static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "This", "Is", "A", "Test", };
protected static final int[] ICONS = new int[] {
        R.drawable.guest,
        R.drawable.home,
        R.drawable.group,
        R.drawable.leaderboard
};

private int mCount = CONTENT.length;

public IconsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return ViewItemTabsActivity.PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position+1);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mCount;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    System.out.println("Got called");
    return IconsPagerAdapter.CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length];
}

@Override
public int getIconResId(int index) {
    System.out.println("This one also got called");
    return ICONS[index % ICONS.length];
}

public void setCount(int count) {
    if (count > 0 && count <= 10) {
        mCount = count;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
}
```

This is the code I have written to create the adapter and the indicator:

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new IconsPagerAdapter(faActivity.getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager.setAdapter((PagerAdapter) mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    TabPageIndicator titleIndicator = (TabPageIndicator)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.titles);
    titleIndicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here is the XML for the llLayout variable. Note that it isn't actually a linear layout, but a ViewPager (I know that it isn't a brilliant name for the variable).

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.groupproject.sharingapp.ViewItemTabsActivity">

<com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/titles"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: Could you also show your llLayout XML code?

Comment: I have edited the question with the XML. It's not actually a LinearLayout, but a ViewPager. I do declare llLayout as a ViewPager earlier in the code.